# else if is not working in my php code , what should i do?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

Hello guys i have a code that receive values from the another page and i want to check if the value equal with on of one values in the array then give me that value so this is my code :

```
**<?php
   session_start();
ob_start();
 //where we get data from the form
if (isset($_POST["btn"])){
    $name=$_POST["name"];
$number=$_POST["number"];
$date=$_POST["fd"].'/'. $_POST["sd"].'/' .$_POST["td"];
    echo $name;
    echo"</br>";
    echo $number;
    echo"</br>";
    echo $date;

    }
$ar=sscanf($date,"%d/%d/%d");

$month1=$ar[1]; // for example the value is 5
```

from the here i have array

```
$month=array(
    "juan"  =>"1",
    "feb"   =>"2",
    "march" =>"3",
    "april" =>"4",
    "may"   =>"5",
    "jun"   =>"6",
    "july"  =>"7",
    "agu"   =>"8",
    "sep"   =>"9",
    "oct"   =>"10",
    "nov"   =>"11",
    "dec"   =>"12"

);
function monthdate($m,$m1){

$flag=false;
foreach ($m1 as $key=>$val){

    $val1=$val;

    if ($val1 == $m){
    $flag=true;
      break;
    }

    else if(!$val1 == $m) {
    $flag=false;}

}
if($flag == true ){
    echo $val1;}

}
echo "your birthday month is ". monthdate($month1,$month);
echo"</br>";
?>**
```

why the function doesn't give me any data ?

Comment: *!$val1 == $m* should probably be $val1 != $m

Comment: @almoo900 Have you checked my updated answer?

Comment: yep but i told you i need the else one for example if my value greater than 12 return some thing and i solved that problem

Comment: @almoo900 check the new updated one... 1 have added 3 answers in my Answer... check the 3rd One

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very strange condition, and probably isn't what you think it is:

```
if(!$val1 == $m)
```

You're *negating* `$val1` (which may not do what you think it does for non-boolean values) and comparing the result of that with `$m`.  Surely you meant this?:

```
if($val1 != $m)
```

Though, even still, you don't need this condition at all.  Your original `if` is comparing these values:

```
if ($val1 == $m)
```

Following that, *all cases where they do not equal* will move to the `else` block.  There's no need for an explicit `if` on that `else` block if it just repeats the negative of the original `if` condition.

Even further, your `else` condition likely isn't necessary in this function at all.  Consider the logic you're implementing... A value is `false` until the first matching result is found, then it's `true` and the loop (and function) completes and exits.  There's no reason to ever reset the value to `false`, so the entire `else` block is unnecessary.

---

Aside from that, based on your usage of the function it looks like you had meant to `return $val1` instead of `echo $val1`.  In the code you're using the two approaches are likely to produce identical results so it may make no difference here, but it's important to understand the difference between the two or you're sure to encounter strange bugs in the future.

---

**Edit:** Based on your comment below, it sounds like you also want some kind of default value for input which doesn't match the data.  You still don't necessarily need the `else`, you can rely on control flow at the end of your function.  For example, where you currently have this:

```
if ($flag == true){
    echo $val1;
}
```

You could do this:

```
if ($flag == true){
    echo $val1;
} else {
    echo "Not found!";
}
```

Or, if you switch to `return` instead of `echo` as suggested above, you could do the same with slightly less code:

```
if ($flag == true){
    return $val1;
}
return "Not found!";
```

Or even:

```
return $flag == true ? $val1 : "Not found!";
```

Comment: so you told me no need to use else so how should i check if value is greater than 12 ?

Comment: @almoo900: It sounds like you just need a default returned value.  I've updated the answer for that.  Indeed, if you switch to `return` instead of `echo` then it would be a good idea to always return something, so this was a good catch on your part.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks man for your answer . i have another question you wrote it didn't need to use else so when should i use else ?

Comment: @almoo900: You'd use it when you need to perform some action if the opposite condition is true.  But in your loop all you're doing is setting the value for `$flag` to either true or false.  Since it's already false, you don't need to set it to false, so the action being performed in your `else` block isn't necessary in this case.  It's not breaking the code in any way, and if you feel it makes the logic more clear for yourself then by all means you can certainly keep it.  It's simply redundant in this case, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

> You can directly parse the loop and when loop gets the required month
>   and monthname, you can directly break the loop or you can return from
>   the function

```
 <?php
    $month1=5;
    $month=array(
        "juan"  =>"1",
        "feb"   =>"2",
        "march" =>"3",
        "april" =>"4",
        "may"   =>"5",
        "jun"   =>"6",
        "july"  =>"7",
        "agu"   =>"8",
        "sep"   =>"9",
        "oct"   =>"10",
        "nov"   =>"11",
        "dec"   =>"12"

    );

    function monthdate($m, $m1)
    {
        foreach ($m1 as $key => $val) 
        {
            if ($val == $m) 
            {
                return $key;
            }
        }    
    }
    echo "Your birthday month is " . monthdate($month1, $month);
    ?>
```

But in my opinion, using ID is a better option with respect to words for comparison.You can achieve the same above result like:

```
<?php
$month1=5;
$month = array(
    "1"=>"jan",
    "2"=>"feb",
    "3"=>"mar",
    "4"=>"apr",
    "5"=>"may",
    "6"=>"jun",
    "7"=>"jul",
    "8"=>"aug",
    "9"=>"sep",
    "10"=>"oct",
    "11"=>"nov",
    "12"=>"dec"
);

function monthdate($m, $m1)
{
    foreach ($m1 as $key => $val) 
    {
        if ($key == $m) 
        {
            return $val;
        }
    }    
}
echo "Your birthday month is " . monthdate($month1, $month);
?>
```

> If you have the option to select value greater than 12,

```
<?php
    $month1=5;
    $month=array(
        "juan"  =>"1",
        "feb"   =>"2",
        "march" =>"3",
        "april" =>"4",
        "may"   =>"5",
        "jun"   =>"6",
        "july"  =>"7",
        "agu"   =>"8",
        "sep"   =>"9",
        "oct"   =>"10",
        "nov"   =>"11",
        "dec"   =>"12"

    );

    function monthdate($m, $m1)
    {
        $flag='';
        foreach ($m1 as $key => $val) 
        {
            if ($val == $m) 
            {
                $flag=$key;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $flag;
    }

    $d = monthdate($month1, $month);
    if(trim($d)==null)
    {
        echo 'Not found';
    }
    else
    {
         echo "Your birthday month is " .$d ;
    }

?>
```

Comment: how about else condition ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$month=array(
    "juan"  =>"1",
    "feb"   =>"2",
    "march" =>"3",
    "april" =>"4",
    "may"   =>"5",
    "jun"   =>"6",
    "july"  =>"7",
    "agu"   =>"8",
    "sep"   =>"9",
    "oct"   =>"10",
    "nov"   =>"11",
    "dec"   =>"12"

);

function Search($value, $array) 
{ 
    return(array_search($value, $array)); 
}

$entered_month= '13';
if($entered_month > 0 && $entered_month <=12){
    echo "your birthday month is ". Search($entered_month,$month);
    echo"</br>";
}else{
  echo "Please enter a valid months";
  echo"</br>";
}
```

Comment: are u kidding me ? for example he wrote 13 and then what ?

Comment: We all know that only 1 to 12 months exist. Code updated please check.